# EF using an inexisting column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I run this code:

```
IEnumerable<Processo> filtrados = db.Processoes
                .Include(s => s.ProcessoClientes)
                .ToList();
```

I got this Exception:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column 'Cliente_ID']

The class ProcessoClientes doesnt have a column named Cliente_ID.

```
public class ProcessoCliente 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PessoaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CondicaoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Condicao Condicao { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ProcessoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Processo Processo { get; set; }
    }
```

And the database table ProcessoClientes doesnt have **too**.

[image]

Then I resolved reset my migrations to get an map of the table in database as EF are seeing it. And I received this:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.ProcessoClientes",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        PessoaID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        CondicaoID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        ProcessoID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Cliente_ID = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Condicaos", t => t.CondicaoID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Clientes", t => t.Cliente_ID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Pessoas", t => t.PessoaID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Processoes", t => t.ProcessoID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.PessoaID)
                .Index(t => t.CondicaoID)
                .Index(t => t.ProcessoID)
                .Index(t => t.Cliente_ID);
```

If this column does not exist in the database table, where is EF bringing it when mounts the migration?

Comment: Most likely the answer is in `Cliente` class you haven't shown. It probably contains something like `public ICollection<ProcessoCliente> ProcessoClientes { get; set; }`

Comment: Thank You Ivan Stoev, That was exactly it.